# filling values in an Array

Tags: swift

I have an array with and index (day) and a value (weight). I want to calculate 'values in between', so all the values that are 0.00 in myArray:

```
typealias Weights = (Double, Double)

var myArray: [Weights] = [ (0.0 , 25.4) , (1.0 , 0.0), (2.0 , 0.0), (3.0 , 0.0), (4.0 , 0.0), (5.0 , 30.3) , (6.0 , 33.5) , (7.0 , 0.0), (8.0 , 0.0), (9.0 , 51.2) , (10.0 , 0.0), (1q.0 , 0.0), (12.0 , 83.1) , (13.0 , 0.0), (14.0 , 0.0), (15.0 , 0.0), (16.0 , 143.0), (17.0 , 0.0), (18.0 , 0.0), (19.0 , 0.0), (20.0 , 0.0), (21.0 , 238.6) , (22.0 , 0.0), (23.0 , 0.0), (24.0 , 311.7) , (25.0 , 322.8) , (26.0 , 0.0), (27.0 , 0.0), (28.0 , 0.0), (29.0 , 460.9) , (30.0 , 0.0), (31.0 , 520.4), (32.0 , 0.0), (33.0 , 0.0),  (34.0 , 0.0), (35.0 , 642.2) , (36.0 , 694.0) , (37.0 , 0.0), (38.0 , 0.0), (39.0 , 0.0), (40.0 , 0.0), (41.0 , 0.0), (42.0 , 0.0), (43.0 , 988.3) , (44.0 , 1018.4) ]
```

For the calculations, it would be something like:

1. values between day 5 and day 0 are 0.00
2. 30.3 - 25.4 = 4.9
3. 4.9 / 5 days = 0.98 per day

so the result for myArray would be:

```
[(0.0 , 25.4) , (1.0 , 26.4) , (2.0 , 27.4) , (3.0 , 28.4) , (4.0 , 28.3) , (5.0 , 30.3)... etc
```

How can I code this?

Comment: Don't use the `Swift4.1` tag unless your question is specific to features unique to that version of the language. You should just use the `swift` tag.

Comment: So the value/weight always increases as the array index increases? And you want to identify runs of entries where the value is 0, and insert interpolated values in those entries so the value changes in even steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this question has got an easy solution for functional programming. Just simple for-each loop.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
typealias Weights = (Double, Double)

var myArray: [Weights] = [ (0.0 , 25.4) , (1.0 , 0.0), (2.0 , 0.0), (3.0 , 0.0), (4.0 , 0.0), (5.0 , 30.3) , (6.0 , 33.5) , (7.0 , 0.0), (8.0 , 0.0), (9.0 , 51.2) , (10.0 , 0.0), (11.0 , 0.0), (12.0 , 83.1) , (13.0 , 0.0), (14.0 , 0.0), (15.0 , 0.0), (16.0 , 143.0), (17.0 , 0.0), (18.0 , 0.0), (19.0 , 0.0), (20.0 , 0.0), (21.0 , 238.6) , (22.0 , 0.0), (23.0 , 0.0), (24.0 , 311.7) , (25.0 , 322.8) , (26.0 , 0.0), (27.0 , 0.0), (28.0 , 0.0), (29.0 , 460.9) , (30.0 , 0.0), (31.0 , 520.4), (32.0 , 0.0), (33.0 , 0.0),  (34.0 , 0.0), (35.0 , 642.2) , (36.0 , 694.0) , (37.0 , 0.0), (38.0 , 0.0), (39.0 , 0.0), (40.0 , 0.0), (41.0 , 0.0), (42.0 , 0.0), (43.0 , 988.3) , (44.0 , 1018.4) ]

print(myArray)
var newArray: [Weights] = []
var nextNonZero = 0
var prevNonZero = nextNonZero
for index in prevNonZero..<myArray.count {
    let weight = myArray[index]
    guard weight.1 == 0 else {
        newArray.append(weight)
        continue
    }
    if index > nextNonZero {
        for innerIndex in index..<myArray.count {
            let innerWeight = myArray[innerIndex]
            let weightParam = innerWeight.1
            if weightParam != 0 {
                prevNonZero = nextNonZero
                nextNonZero = innerIndex
                break
            }
        }
    }
    print(prevNonZero, nextNonZero)
    let prevWeight = myArray[prevNonZero]
    let nextWeight = myArray[nextNonZero]
    let stepsNumber = Double(nextNonZero - prevNonZero)
    let difference = nextWeight.1 - prevWeight.1
    guard stepsNumber != 0 else {
        newArray.append((weight.0 , 0))
        continue
    }
    let step = difference / stepsNumber

    let differenceNumber = Double(index - prevNonZero)
    let differenceValue = step * differenceNumber
    let newValue = prevWeight.1 + differenceValue
    newArray.append((weight.0 , newValue))
}

print(newArray)
```

Comment: Thanks, Vyacheslav... that works fine. I'm going to integrate that in my app!

Comment: Hi Vyacheslav, there is a bug... if myArray: [Weights] = [ (0.0 , 0.0) , (1.0 , 0.0), (2.0 , 0.0), (3.0 , 0.0), (4.0 , 0.0), (5.0 , 30.3) , (6.0 , 33.5) etc... the results for newArray are: [(0.0, -nan), (1.0, 6.0600000000000005), (2.0, 12.120000000000001), (3.0, 18.18), (4.0, 24.240000000000002) etc. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @arakweker you have not tried to think. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Vyacheslav, thanks again. Certainly I 'tried' for a couple of hours, but I just didn't see it. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In-place approach using `Swift 5`

```
typealias Weights = (Double, Double)
var myArray: [Weights] =  [ (0.0 , 25.4) , (1.0 , 0.0), (2.0 , 0.0), (3.0 , 0.0), (4.0 , 0.0), (5.0 , 30.3) , (6.0 , 33.5) , (7.0 , 0.0), (8.0 , 0.0), (9.0 , 51.2) , (10.0 , 0.0), (11.0 , 0.0), (12.0 , 83.1) , (13.0 , 0.0), (14.0 , 0.0), (15.0 , 0.0), (16.0 , 143.0), (17.0 , 0.0), (18.0 , 0.0), (19.0 , 0.0), (20.0 , 0.0), (21.0 , 238.6) , (22.0 , 0.0), (23.0 , 0.0), (24.0 , 311.7) , (25.0 , 322.8) , (26.0 , 0.0), (27.0 , 0.0), (28.0 , 0.0), (29.0 , 460.9) , (30.0 , 0.0), (31.0 , 520.4), (32.0 , 0.0), (33.0 , 0.0),  (34.0 , 0.0), (35.0 , 642.2) , (36.0 , 694.0) , (37.0 , 0.0), (38.0 , 0.0), (39.0 , 0.0), (40.0 , 0.0), (41.0 , 0.0), (42.0 , 0.0), (43.0 , 988.3) , (44.0 , 1018.4), (45.0 , 0.0) ]
fillInBetween(&myArray)
print(myArray)

func fillInBetween(_ arr: inout [Weights])
{
    guard let firstNonZeroInd = arr.firstIndex(where: {$0.1 != 0}),
        let lastNonZeroInd = arr.lastIndex(where: {$0.1 != 0}) else { return }
    
    var ind = firstNonZeroInd
    while ind != lastNonZeroInd
    {
        let nextInd = arr[(ind+1)...].firstIndex(where: {$0.1 != 0})!
        let valueStep = (arr[nextInd].1 - arr[ind].1) / Double(nextInd - ind)
        for i in (ind+1)..<nextInd {
            arr[i].1 = arr[i-1].1 + valueStep
        }
        ind = nextInd
    }
}
```